# How can I get the nearest Place (Village Or Street name)

Tags: android, gps, geocoding, google-places-api, reverse-geocoding

In my application, when the user insert data i want to capture the user's exact place. I've tried so many methods. But none of them shown the exact place. (I meant that they display the country and admin area details only. I used getLocality and getFeatureName. If no Locality or Featurename found at that latitude and longitude then it will return a null value). My code is

```
Geocoder coder=new Geocoder(MainActivity.mContext,Locale.getDefault());
    try
    {
        List<Address> listaddress=coder.getFromLocation(lat, lon, 1);
        Address obj=listaddress.get(0);
        String add=obj.getAddressLine(0);
        add = add+"\n"+obj.getLatitude();
        add = add+","+obj.getLongitude();
        add = add + "," + obj.getCountryName();
        add = add + "," + obj.getAdminArea();
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getPostalCode();//null
        add = add + "," + obj.getSubAdminArea();
        add = add +","+obj.getFeatureName();//null
        add = add+ "," +obj.getPremises();//null
        add = add + "\n" + obj.getLocality();//null
        add = add + "," + obj.getSubThoroughfare();//null
        add = add+ "," +obj.getSubLocality();//null
        add = add+"\n"+obj.getThoroughfare();

        Log.v("IGA", "Address" + add);
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Address=>" + add,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        t.setText(" "+add);


    }
```

So I don't know how to solve it. But I have an idea. I need to find the nearest place to my exact latitude and longitude value, so that i can use that place. But I don't know how to find the nearest place (Nearest place means Village or Street not any others).

Also, In Android phones one application "Places" is there. It shows the correct area about where exactly I'm. Is there any possibilities to use the application "Places" to find my exact or nearest area. (I need the closest village or street, not subAdminArea (state). If yes, please explain.

Can anyone help me please

Comment: do geocoding to get the exact name of your location

Comment: try with this one.. in this you will get the details about getting address from location . http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: I need it without displaying the map

Comment: in that they will be processing it using location to address.. so just grab that work for your requirement

Comment: for that you have to go for google service

Answer (score 0):

Using google reverse geocoding api you could get your actual street address by giving latitude and lantitude values.

[Get Lat & Lan through GPS Receiver in Android](http://www.incurlybraces.com/gps-location-coordinates-android.html)

Then call google reverse geocoding api top fecth the actual street address:

```
  MapManager in = new MapManager(
                    "http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?output=xml&oe=utf-8&ll="
                            + lattitude                             + "%2C"
                            + lantitude                         + "&key=get-key-from-google-map-api");
            content = in.URLRequest();
            System.out.println("Addrss:"+in.parseMapData(content));

Class MapManager{
  String url ="";

  MapManager(String url){
         this.url = url;
  }

  public String parseMapData(String data) {
            String addr = "";
            try {
                InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
                DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
                        .newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = builder.parse(in, null);
                NodeList address = doc.getElementsByTagName("address");
                addr = address.item(0).getTextContent();
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                Log.v("Exception", "Exception: " + t.toString());
            }
            return addr;
        }



     public String URLRequest() {

        httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            httpget = new HttpGet(url);
            httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httpget);
            httpentity = httpresponse.getEntity();
            response = EntityUtils.toString(httpentity);
            response = response.trim();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            IsServerConn = false;
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            IsServerConn = false;
        }
        return response;

    }

}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer content is the response which is response of that request.

Answer (score 0):

```
   private class MatchingNearByLocationTask extends
        AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getContext());
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        progressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

        jsonStr = getLocationInfo(latitude, longitude).toString(); // put longitude and      latitude value from which u want find nearer palce
        if (jsonStr != null) {
            Log.i("location--??", jsonStr);

            JSONObject jsonObj;
            try {
                jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                JSONObject responseJsonObject = jsonObj
                        .getJSONObject("response");

                JSONArray venues = responseJsonObject
                        .getJSONArray(("venues"));

                for (int index = 0; index < venues.length(); index++) {

                    locationObject = new NearByLocationObject();

                    String id = "", name = "", longitude = "", latitude = "";

                    JSONObject venuesJsonObj = venues.getJSONObject(index);

                    id = venuesJsonObj.getString("id");
                    name = venuesJsonObj.getString("name");

                    JSONObject latLngJsonObj = venuesJsonObj
                            .getJSONObject("location");

                    longitude = latLngJsonObj.getString("lng");
                    latitude = latLngJsonObj.getString("lat");

                    locationObject.setId(id);
                    locationObject.setNameOfLocation(name);
                    locationObject.setLocationOfLatitude(latitude);
                    locationObject.setLocationOfLongitude(longitude);

                    nearByLocationArrayList.add(locationObject);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        adapter = new NearByLocationArrayAdapter(getContext(),
                R.layout.nearby_location_item, nearByLocationArrayList);
        nearByLocationListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {

        super.onCancelled();
        progressDialog.dismiss();

    }

}

private JSONObject getLocationInfo(double lat, double lng) {

    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
            "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll="
                    + lat
                    + ","
                    + lng
                    + "&radius=100&oauth_token=TNFKWLITLCJYWPSLAXQNHCSDPHZ4IS5PWVDD45OI224JGFFM&v=20140407&intent=checkin");
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response;
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        response = client.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
        int b;
        while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
            stringBuilder.append((char) b);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}



public class NearByLocationObject {

String id = "", nameOfLocation, locationOfLatitude, LocationOfLongitude;

public NearByLocationObject() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public NearByLocationObject(String id, String nameOfLocation,
        String locationOfLatitude, String locationOfLongitude) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.nameOfLocation = nameOfLocation;
    this.locationOfLatitude = locationOfLatitude;
    LocationOfLongitude = locationOfLongitude;
}

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNameOfLocation() {
    return nameOfLocation;
}

public void setNameOfLocation(String nameOfLocation) {
    this.nameOfLocation = nameOfLocation;
}

public String getLocationOfLatitude() {
    return locationOfLatitude;
}

public void setLocationOfLatitude(String locationOfLatitude) {
    this.locationOfLatitude = locationOfLatitude;
}

public String getLocationOfLongitude() {
    return LocationOfLongitude;
}

public void setLocationOfLongitude(String locationOfLongitude) {
    LocationOfLongitude = locationOfLongitude;
}
```

}